# Multiple xsl choose conditions

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have 2 condition to check true or false and take a certain action.

Here is my code.

```
<xsl:variable name="hac" select="Hac1"/>



<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$hac= 'false'">
    <p style="display:inline">Hac1: </p><input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" >
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
    <p>HACCP: </p><input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" checked="checked">
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>

<xsl:variable name="glo1" select="Gloves"/>
    <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test1="$glo1= 'false'">
    <p style="display:inline">Gloves: </p><input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" >
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
    <p>Gloves: </p><input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" checked="checked">
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

This only displays my Hac1 and not my Gloves, and i don't know what seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is a direct copy/paste from your XSLT, you have several errors, so I'm amazed you actually get anything.

All four of the `<input>` tags are missing their closure, so change the final part from `>` to `/>` on each one... for example...

```
<input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" />
```

Then you have `<xsl:when test1=...` which is incorrect.  It should be `<xsl:when test=...` (note the lack of the `1`)...

```
 <xsl:when test="$glo1= 'false'">
```

Comment: I found the closure issue myself,but haven't seen the test1 name, thank you so much i would have wasted so much time on such trivial matter.

Comment: You're welcome, @Aleks, but I must ask what you are using to parse the XSLT?  Because (as Dimitre points out) any compliant XSLT processor should have failed to produce **anything** with the XSLT you provided.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog       :D

Comment: @Aleks, if I may make a suggestion, do NOT use w3schools as a reference... it is a terrible website and widely disliked across the StackOverflow comunity (you can see exactly why at http://w3fools.com).  If they have an XSLT parser that actually allows your original XSLT to run, then it just demonstrates how bad it is!!

Comment: Fully support @freefaller on the quality and usefulness of w3schools :)

Answer (score 1):

**The provided XSLT code has a number of obvious errors** and any compliant XSLT processor (or even XML parser) should raise errors and not produce any output at all:

1. The `<input>` elements aren't closed -- this males the whole stylesheet non-well-formed XML document.
2. The `<xsl:when>` instruction cannot have an attribute named `"test1"` -- only "test" attribute is allowed.

**When I corrected these two errors, the transformation now is**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:variable name="hac" select="Hac1"/>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$hac= 'false'">
        <p style="display:inline">Hac1: </p><input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <p>HACCP: </p><input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" checked="checked"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>

    <xsl:variable name="glo1" select="Gloves"/>
     <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$glo1= 'false'">
        <p style="display:inline">Gloves: </p><input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <p>Gloves: </p><input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" checked="checked"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**and it produces normal-looking results**.

**When applied on this XML document** (none was provided!):

```
<t>
 <Hac1>true</Hac1>
 <Floves>false</Floves>
</t>
```

**the result is**:

```
<p>HACCP: </p>
<input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" checked="checked"/>
<p>Gloves: </p>
<input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" checked="checked"/>
```